# ¿How can I connect node.js with mssql server with module mssql?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, module, connection, node-mssql

That is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql');
var path  = require('path'),
    html5 = require('ejs').__express;

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.engine('.html', html5 );
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var config = {
    user: 'dbo',
    password: '',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'db_name'
}

sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    // ... error checks

    // Query

    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query('select * from table_name', function(err, recordset) {
        // ... error checks

        console.log(recordset);

        app.get('/', function(request, response) {

            response.send(err);

        });


    });



});
```

In console recordset set me the message: "undefined"
and in localhost:3000 the message is: "Login failed; one or more errorMessage events should have been emitted" I'm using MSSQLSERVER 2012. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

After many days, I decided to connect MSSQL Server with PHP because I thought was easiest but I found the same problem: Login failed. Then I was trying to connect and saw the real trouble: Windows auth. Conclusion: the right way to work with module mssql is sql server auth and available port 1433.

```
//e.g.:
var config = {
user: 'sa',
password: '******',
server: 'ip_server',
database: 'db_name'
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on if you got mssql to work with node? I am having an issue where it just sais undefined when i try and log in

Comment: I forgot to say this configuration works fine with nodejs, too.